# How to read this text file and search for course name Java?

Tags: java

I try to get my code to work however when I run it there is nothing getting printed on my screen. I would like the user to enter a course code and then be presented with the name of the course. I want to use a HashMap to do this, however after some struggles thought id ask here for some suggestion.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class reading_a_file {

static void pull_info(String courseCode) throws IOException{
    
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("CourseSample.txt"));
     
     Map<String, String> course_info = new HashMap<String, String>();
    
     String line;
    String[] data;

    while(((line = read.readLine()) != null))
   {
       line = read.readLine();
       data = line.split(" ");
       String courseID = data[0];
       String courseName = data[1];
         
       course_info.put(courseID, courseName);
       if(courseCode==courseID){
    System.out.println(course_info.get(courseName));
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
    String course_code;
    
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to text file formatter by XM21");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Please enter course id to see description (-1 to exit):");
    System.out.println("CourseCode:");
    course_code = console.nextLine();
    
    
    pull_info(course_code);

}
}
```

and this is what my text file looks like :
[image: textfile]

sample of text file (just copy and paste to notepad) :

ITE221 Database Management System

ITE222 Web Development I  Pre: ITE221 ITE232

ITE223 Cloud Technology Pre: ITE222

ITE224 Mobile Application Development I Pre: ITE 222

Comment: can you put sample CourseSample.txt file?

Comment: You put the the key courseID in the hashmap and then you are trying to access the value at courseName(instead of course_info.get(courseName), put course_info.get(courseID))

Comment: ok iv added it in text form could not upload the actual file

Comment: tried it still no luck @M. Aroosi

Comment: Added an answer below with a few code changes that could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in this code that can cause this issue.

1) You're calling `line = read.nextLine()` twice in a row, so you're only looking at every second line.

2) Most of your course names have a space in them - meaning that even when you happen to land on the course you wanted during your search, you will only print out the first word of the course name.

3) Strings should be compared with equals, or equalsIngnoreCase - not the "==" sign which is for other comparisons.

4) Scanners are a resource - remember to close it!

5) when printing a value of the Map - use get(key) with the key, not the value.

You could improve the code by changing a few things:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class reading_a_file {

  static void pull_info(String courseCode) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CourseSample.txt"));

    Map<String, String> course_info = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String line;
    String[] data;

    while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
      data = line.split(" ");
      String courseID = data[0];
      String courseName = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ")+1);

      course_info.put(courseID, courseName);
      if (courseCode.equalsIgnoreCase(courseID)) {
        System.out.println(courseName);
      }
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String course_code;

    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to text file formatter by XM21");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Please enter course id to see description (-1 to exit):");
    System.out.println("CourseCode:");
    course_code = console.nextLine();

    pull_info(course_code);
    console.close();

  }
}
```

Comment: @DanielGoncalves Fixed. I added the reason why it printed null as my number 5 tip.

Comment: exactly what i needed thanks for the help really appreciate it mate :-)

Comment: @DanielGoncalves, if it solved your problem - would you mind accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark next to it, making it green?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot compare two `String` variables with `==` operator, you have to use `equals()`.

And there are other different errors, like "line = read.readLine()" inside the `while` loop and the `course_info.get(courseName)` as **you should use the key to get the value** in your `HashMap`, and not the value to get the key.

#### Edit your block like this:

```
while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
   // line = read.readLine(); // no need for this
   data = line.split(" ");
   String courseID = data[0];
   String courseName = data[1];
   course_info.put(courseID, courseName);
   if (courseCode.equals(courseID)) { // correct comparation between String variables
        System.out.println(course_info.get(courseID)); // the hashmap retreives the right value now
    }
}
```

#### Edit

If you want to output all the strings after the Id you just have to add something really easy like

```
data = line.split(" ");
String courseID = data[0];

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    sb.append(data[i]);

    if (i < data.length - 1) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
}

String courseName = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you alot :-) is there any way i could make it show database management systems instead of just database

Comment: still only printing the first word of the course name not the full name

Comment: Also, your String.split() on spaces won't work; it splits on every word, causing courseName to be only the first word after the first space. You'd better use String().indexOf() to find the first space and then String.substring() to get both parts. Or, if you're allowed to modify the input file, just use a CSV file with a comma or semi-colon as separator character and use String.split() on that character.

Comment: thank for the help ill edit the text file to make it more workable :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 major issues in your code.

**1st issue:-**

I see, you have put multiple readLine in your code

```
    while(((line = read.readLine()) != null))
   {
       line = read.readLine(); // No need for this.
```

**2nd issue:-**
You should use String equal method

```
if(courseCode==courseID) // this is not good, as it's object comparsion.
```

Following code should be used. It will compare the string value.

```
 if( courseCode.equals(courseID))
```

**3rd issue:-** You are not using right key for getting element from hashmap. Use CourseID

```
    if (courseCode.equals(courseID)) {
        System.out.println(course_info.get(courseID));
    }
```

This is the complete program for you. This can be optimized further.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class reading_a_file {

    static void pull_info(String courseCode) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CourseSample.txt"));

        Map<String, String> course_info = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String line;
        String[] data;


        while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
            data = line.split(" ");
            String courseID = data[0];
            String courseName = data[1];

            course_info.put(courseID, courseName);
            if (courseCode.equals(courseID)) {
                System.out.println(course_info.get(courseID));
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String course_code;

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Welcome to text file formatter by XM21");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter course id to see description (-1 to exit):");
        System.out.println("CourseCode:");
        course_code = console.nextLine();

        pull_info(course_code);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the '==' operator for comparing String instances. This only checks if the two String instances share the same reference.
Replace '==' for the equals() method.

```
 courseID.equals(courseCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "courseCode.equals(courseID)" instead of "courseCode==courseID". "==" compares references and it can be used for string literals, not for the strings created as "new String()", probably String.split() give you the array of strings created as "new String()" for each word. Be careful with the character casing also when putting it in a map.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the already pointed out issues, you will most likely have to provide a full path to the file.

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("CourseSample.txt"));
```

To something like this

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Drive/Folder/User/Desktop/file.txt"));
```